# Loading my own service in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchbase

What's the best solution for providing a global couchbase connection in my rails application.
I'm also using ActiveRecord so I don't need [couchbase-ruby-model](https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-model)

The couchbase connection should be accessible from all my controllers. I wan't to avoid creating a new connection everytime a couchbase connection is needed.

Comment: I haven't used couchbase but the whole idea with ActiveRecord is that the ORM handles database connections and its done on the model level - not in controllers. You could use a global variable but it just seems like a huge anti-pattern.

Comment: Than let's see couchbase like a service. In my case it's more used like a service then like a database. For example think about a services that takes the name of a city and returns geographical information. Where would you place such a service?

Comment: In rails you don't really have the whole "services" layer like in Laravel or Symfony. There are plenty of gems which provide it but its not cannon - DHH is pretty opposed to dependency injection.

Comment: models are one place to write globally-available code, but not the only. You can write any file you like in `app/models` or `config/initializers` and it will be autoloaded - it doesn't have to be ActiveRecord. There are guides to add other paths, like lib/ or services/ , to autoload as well.